# Output equal null

Tags: java, string

I've been trying to create a program but I'm struggling because of an error that is causing `Null` to be output.

> - **Problem statement :**  You have been given a secret mission where you must break the enemy's code. You have already figured out that
>     they encode messages using the following method. Each letter between
>     'a' and 'z', inclusive, is assigned a distinct two-digit number
>     between 01 and 26, inclusive. A message is encoded by simply replacing
>     each letter with its assigned number. For example, if 't' is assigned
>     20, 'e' is assigned 05 and 's' is assigned 19, then the message "test"
>     is encoded as "20051920". All original messages contain only lowercase
>     letters.   Given assignment of numbers to letters and the encoded
>     message, you need to figure out the original message.
>
>   - **Input:** First line will contain an integer T = number of test cases. Each test case will contain two lines. First line will contain
>       a string of 26 characters containing the assignment of numbers to
>       letters. The first letter of this string is assigned 01, the second is
>       assigned 02 and so on. Next line will contain encoded message.
>   - **Output:** For each test case, decode and print the original message.

- **Code**

  public class SecretCode {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          int temp = sc.nextInt();

  ```
      for (int l = 0; l < temp; l++) {
          String code = sc.next();
          Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
          int i = 1;

          for (int k = 0; k < code.length(); k++) {
              if (i < 10) {
                  String b = "0" + i;
                  //int bint=Integer.parseInt(b);
                  ht.put(code.charAt(k), b);
              } else {
                  String istrb = "";
                  istrb += i;

                  ht.put(code.charAt(k), istrb);
              }
              i++;
          }

          String numcode = sc.next();
          String[] arr = new String[numcode.length() / 2];
          int index = 0;
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(40);
          String s = "";
          for (int j = 0; j < numcode.length(); j++) {
              if (j % 2 != 0 || j == 0) {
                  s = s + numcode.charAt(j);
                  arr[index] = s;
              }

              if (j % 2 == 0 && j != 0) {
                  index++;
                  s = "";
                  s = s + numcode.charAt(j);
                  arr[index] = s;
              }
          }

          StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(40);
          String str1 = "";
          for (int m = 0; m < arr.length; m++) {
              String arrel = arr[m];
              System.out.print(ht.get(arrel));
          }
          System.out.println(str);
      }
  }
  ```

---

**Sample Input and Output**

2

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

> 20051920

faxmswrpnqdbygcthuvkojizle

> 02170308060416192402

Comment: can you provide an example of input and output?

Comment: At the first glance, I see that you are putting `char` keys into the map but try to lookup `String` keys later on. Using Generics helps avoiding such mistakes. Besides that, I see a lot of unused variables which indicate insufficient thinking about what you are actually doing. Why do you create the `StringBuffer` stored in `sb` or the one stored in `str`? Why do you print out `str` when you never used it? What’s the purpose of `str1`? Etc.

Comment: It seems you're storing figures from "01" to "10" and more but you're actually looking for figures from "0" to "9". You also should think about @Holger's comment.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestions, i'll definitely consider everything but I dnt understand why is the output coming out to be null when till the second last line the code is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the information in map. As we know that it will always be `26 characters`, so can store them in a `char array` and access them directly by `indexes`. Next you know that each char is represented by `two char digit`, so fetch the `sub strings` and convert them to `number` and access the char array directly. I have used `StringBuilder` here to store the output.

Here is my implementation of the problem:

```java
public class SecretCode {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = scanner.nextInt();
    while (t>0) {
      t--;
      char chars[] = scanner.next().toCharArray();
      String msg = scanner.next();
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i=0; i<msg.length();) {
        String number = msg.substring(i, i+2);
        Integer num = Integer.parseInt(number);
        builder.append(chars[num-1]);
        i = i+2;
      }
      System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Abhishek, Ur code is working absolutely fine and its very effective and precise also.